# Xamarin - Datepicker not displaying properly

Tags: datepicker, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms, xamarin.forms-styles

In **Xamarin.Forms - Android**, I'm trying to use **DatePicker**.

```
<StackLayout>
  <DatePicker VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" Date="{x:Static sys:DateTime.Now}">
    <DatePicker.Format>yyyy-MM-dd</DatePicker.Format>
    <DatePicker.MinimumDate>
      <sys:DateTime x:FactoryMethod="Parse">
        <x:Arguments>
          <x:String>Jan 1 2000</x:String>
        </x:Arguments>
      </sys:DateTime>
    </DatePicker.MinimumDate>
    <DatePicker.MaximumDate>
      <sys:DateTime x:FactoryMethod="Parse">
        <x:Arguments>
          <x:String>Dec 31 2050</x:String>
        </x:Arguments>
      </sys:DateTime>
    </DatePicker.MaximumDate>
  </DatePicker>
</StackLayout>
```

Any one have any idea why my datepicker is being displayed like this? Please, see the image below.

[image]

Please help me if anyone has any idea.

Comment: Add image, please.

Comment: @EgorGromadskiy i added image please see

Comment: I copied your codes into a blank empty project, but didn't reproduced the problem. Could you please share a demo that can reproduce the problem?

Comment: note: you don't have to use DateTime.Parse for setting dates. If you specify a string, the Xaml Loader will invoke DateTime.Parse() with invariant culture for you. When you explicitly invoke Parse(), it will use the current culture of the app, and the parsing can fail on non en-us cultures.